# Antlr4 semantic predicates to parse a date

Tags: date, antlr4, semantics, predicate

I started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651518/how-to-create-a-antlr4-grammar-which-will-parse-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr) to come up with the following start, but I am getting the error: "Problems calling org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(args)". If someone could tell me where I am messing up I would appreciate it

Form to parse : dd/mm/yyyy

- dd must be between 01 and 31
- mm must be between 01 and 12

  ```
  lexer grammar dates;

  fragment DIGIT: [0123456789];

  DATE : DAY ('/'MONTH+) ('/'YEAR+)
      {System.out.println(getText() + " is a valid Date");};

  DAY : TWODIGIT
      {Integer.parseInt(getText()) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(getText()) <= 31}?;
  MONTH : TWODIGIT
      {Integer.parseInt(getText()) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(getText()) <= 12}?;
  YEAR : FOURDIGIT
      {Integer.parseInt(getText()) >= 2000 && Integer.parseInt(getText()) <= 2100}?;

  TWODIGIT : DIGIT DIGIT;
  FOURDIGIT : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
  WS: [\r\n\t]+{skip();};
  ```

Does the problem have to do with the fact that according to how things are currently, all months are days?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that the posted grammar is incomplete?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am completely brand new to Antlr, could you maybe explain a bit more to help me out?

Comment: The grammar statement is missing. You really need to read the documentation or, better, the TDAR, to learn Antlr properly.