# How to "skip" a rule in order to favor one rule over the other?

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm currrently building a date parser using antlr. The inputs it takes are

```
year monthName numDayOfMonth era
numDayOfMonth monthName year era
```

These are all under the rule `stringDate`, so my grammar looks like this

```
stringDate: year monthName numDayOfMonth
|           numDayOfMonth monthName year; 

numYear:               NUMBER ;
strMonth:              MONTH  ;
numDayOfMonth:         NUMBER ;

NUMBER:    [0-9]+ ;
MONTH:     'jan' | 'feb' | 'mar' | 'apr' | 'jun' | 'jul' | 'aug' | 'sep' | 'sept' | 'oct' | 'nov' | 'dec' ;
```

In my listeners, I check to make sure that `numDayOfMonth` is within the range `[1, 31]` to make sure that that the number is a valid date. I do the same for the months (first I transform them into their corresponding month).

The problem is, if it input the date `2013 June 13`, The date gets parsed correctly. However, when I input `13 June 2013`, it gets parsed incorrectly because the parser gets confused and thinks 2013 is a day, not a year, and therefore the check fails during `exitNumDayOfMonth`. I've been scratching my head about how to handle this. I essentially want the evaluator to skip the rule of i encounter a `num > 31`, but I'm not entirely sure of how to skip a rule. I have tried `return`ing, and throwing errors, but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to make the evaluator skip this rule and go on to the alternative instead?

Comment: doesn't antlr have a date class?  In any case if your year is always 4 digits, parse the string and find that first.  Then find the non-numeric month and extract that.  You'll then be left with the day.  Also you could check stack overflow.  There are already a few threads on parsing dates in antlr.  Here's one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651518/how-to-create-a-antlr4-grammar-which-will-parse-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you change the token definition of year to contain only 4 digits? That will solve the issue.

So, your year and date will be

```
numYear: [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9]
  numDayOfMonth: [0-9] | [0-9] [0-9]
```

Currently, they both have same definition - so the parser does not know which rule to pick while parsing and goes with the first one which fits the input.